# Best approach for flow chart (Workflow) execution in java

Tags: java, workflow

I am writing module for flow chart execution.The flow chart contains number of task to be performed.each task has it's own functionality.I'm using graph to store flow execution.I'm using directed acyclic  graph to store it.

DirectedGraph.java

```
public class DirectedGraph<T> implements Iterable<T> , Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<T,Set<T>> graph = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public boolean addNode(T node){
        if(graph.containsKey(node))
            return false;

        //Add node to the graph
        graph.put(node, Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<T>()));
        return true;        
    }
    public void addEdge(T start,T end){

        if(!graph.containsKey(start) || !graph.containsKey(end))
            throw new NoSuchElementException("One or both of the vertex are missing.");

        /*Adding edge in the graph*/
        graph.get(start).add(end);
    }
/*
Other method for iterator,size etc.
*/
}
```

After adding to graph I'm performing topological sort.after performing sort i'm getting list of task.

task has following strcuture.

```
class Task{
    int id;  
    int activityId;
    String activityType;
    ArratList<Integer> inputIds;
    ArratList<Integer> outputIds;
}
```

Each task has it's own id. inputIds contains it's dependent task and outputIds contains which task need to be performed.activity type can be [ Task ,Decision ].

I think it's like an workflow execution.so what is the best approaches to perform workflow execution.

Answer (score 0):

Both of my suggested are based on processing the topologically sorted node list.

**Polymorphic Tasks/Decisions**
Give Task an abstract method `void execute(ExecutionContext context)`. Each TaskType has its own implementation where all changes to the execution context are done. The result type might differ if you want to return information (e.g. if flow should continue). You should prefer this if you have only one pass and do not expect multiple passes on the same list.

**Visitor/Interpreter**
Use the visitor design pattern, add a method `void apply(TaskVisitor visitor)`. TaskVisitor has one visitXXX-method per activityType. This approach is recommended if you have different passed to do on the task list (like, type checking, validation, interpretation).

In both cases it is better to use different subtypes of Task to distinguish the different activity types (you actually use a field activityType), because you then can distinguish different behaviour in a polymorphic way instead of using if/switch-cascades.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a framework called [Dexecutor](https://github.com/dexecutor) for these kind of usecases, you can have a look at the [source code](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-core), and explore best practices and design pattern used. You can find similar [datastructure](https://dexecutor.github.io/current/apidocs/com/github/dexecutor/core/graph/DependencyAware.html).

Here is a [workflow example](https://github.com/dexecutor/dexecutor-examples#2-workflow-example) which can be acheived using Dexecutor

[image: dexecutor-workflow-example.png]

Comment: help appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for? @VishveshPhadnis